# Serious table problems - something is wrong the text cell (it just continue?)

Tags: tables, tabularx, dcolumn

TWO MORE QUESTIONS:

How do I add analyzes to the left side (so the letter turns into the figure and with  a underline?)? And how do I remove "Game"-catogory, if I would like that??

[image]

It would be a huge help - Thank you so much!!

As mentioned in title I would like to know how to break one a line (it doesn't work for me!). I would like my figure to look like this - but it won't work(!):
[image]

But it looks like this:
[image]

My preamble is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article} 
\usepackage[english,danish]{babel} 
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 
\usepackage{layout}
\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22} 
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
\addto\captionsdanish{
\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendiks}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Indhold}
\renewcommand\refname{Litteratur}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Figur}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm,mathtools}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.6}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[round, colon, sort, authoryear]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{}
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
\def\citeapos#1{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc, matrix} 
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,caption,subcaption,booktabs,threeparttable}
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{{}^{#1}} % correct?
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand\narrowtab[2]{%  %% macro to hide depth of its argument from outer tabular
 \ensuremath{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{}}%
     #2 \end{tabular}}}}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteLabel}[1]{#1}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\renewcommand\tabcolsep{1pt}  
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} p{1.7in} @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{5}{D{,}{,}{2.4}} @{}}
\toprule
\mc{Hypotese nr. }& \mc{Method} & \mc{Game} \\
\midrule
1 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY \\
2 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY \\
3 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY \\
4 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\vspace{-0.6em}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That does not look like a tabular. More like an itemization. But to be honest, i can't figure out, why there is so much stoff. Espeacialy the multicols, the D columns etc. But then again, all you gave is `TEXT TEXT`. Can you make the example more minimal (why is there bib stuff included?) and maybe replace TEXT by `\blindtext`.

Comment: Because I am starting to set up my paper, so I am starting creating my table, then bib, then the content. :)

Comment: How would you create the opposite table/model then?

Comment: you haven't given an alignment specification for the first column, so that is using the "paragraph" spec unnecessarily.  insert `c` before the `p{...}` in the template to take care of that problem; there may be others, but this needs to be fixed first.

Comment: @Johannes_B is not saying that stuff doesn't belong in your *paper*! But it doesn't belong in your [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you gave doesn't qualify as a MWE. You have to use `p` type columns as for the given table `D` column is useless.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteLabel}[1]{#1}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
%\renewcommand\tabcolsep{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}>{\raggedright}m{0.68\textwidth}
    p{\dimexpr0.17\textwidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
\toprule
\mc{Hypotese nr.}& \mc{Method} & \mc{Game}  \\
\midrule
1 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY \\
2 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY \\
3 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY \\
4 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\vspace{-0.6em}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Harish Kumar. One last thing, how to place "1", "2" etc. and "Falsify" in the middle of each line? Is that possible?

Comment: @A.F. Use `m` column for the middle one. See the update.

Comment: Dear Harish Kumar. I talked with my fellow, and me and him couldn't remove the third coloum "Game", if we would like to. Could you maybe make an extra script of how we do that? (We tried to remove all "Falsify" and "&". We would also like to know, whether it is possible to put 1. analyze" and "2. analyze" into the cell to the left (please see the first picture). Is that possible, and could you show us that too? We really appreciate your help!!